# Unable to install g++ in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, g++

This is my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:6.3.1-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

:~$ g++
The program g++ is not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install g++
```

I've tried to install build-essentials and gcc and also had the same problem.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install g++   --reinstall`

Comment: Do you get any output when you run the command `man g++ | less`  (a yes or no answer is sufficient). `which g++` should return `/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -l g++` and `which g++`

Comment: you can use: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears something removed the symbolic link at `/usr/bin/g++` that is normally set up during the installation of the `g++` package. You can either

- reinstall the package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
  ```
- or tell `update-alternative`, which normally manages the symbolic link at `/usr/bin/g++`, to reconfigure the link:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --auto g++
  ```